# Integral domain with a quotient field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

> Let  $A$ be an integral domain with the quotient field $K=S^{-1} A$, where $S=A\setminus\{0\}$. Then in $K$ the following equalities hold: $A=\bigcap_{P\in Spec A} A_P = \bigcap_{M \in Spm A} A_M$.

The above question is from my assignment in commutative algebra and I have tried it two times.

I think the method should assuming taking element in 1 set and proving it to be in another set. I want to prove that $A=\bigcap_{P\in Spec A} A_P$--(1) and $\bigcap_{P\in Spec A} A_P = \bigcap_{M \in Spm A} A_M$--(2).

For 1st  equality: Let $x\in A$. But I am not really sure how should I proceed.

If $x\in \bigcap_{P\in SpecA} A_P$, then x lies in $A_P$ for all prime ideals P.Again I am confused how to approach.

I shall be really grateful if you can give some hints on this problem. I am really unable to proceed. I have been following atiyah and macdonald.

Comment: The first thing you should think about is what does it mean to intersect two localizations. Abstractly, this does not make sense, as $S^{-1}A$ and $T^{-1}A$ are two "new" sets. But in this problem, you can identify each localization inside $K$, and do the intersection there. Having that it mind, you should try to prove the two $\subseteq$ inclusions first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $x\in K$ you have an ideal $I_x\subseteq A$ consisting of elements $b$ such that $bx\in A$.  For any $x\in K$ there are two possibilities: $I_x=A$ or $I_x\subseteq M$ for some $M\in {\rm Spm}(A)$.

In the first case $x\in A$, and in the second case $x\notin A_M$.  Thus $$\cap_{M\in {\rm Spm(A)}} A_M\subseteq A.$$

The inclusions: $$A\subseteq\cap_{P\in {\rm Spec}(A)} A_P\subseteq\cap_{M\in {\rm Spm}(A)} A_M,$$
follow trivially from $A\subseteq A_P$ for all primes $P$ and ${\rm Spm}(A)\subseteq {\rm Spec}(A)$.

Comment: How does you deduced the fact that $A\subseteq A_P$  for all primes P?

Comment: also , kindly tell how exactly you deduced $\cap_{P\in {\rm Spec}(A)} A_P\subseteq\cap_{M\in {\rm Spm}(A)} A_M$?

Comment: What is the definition of $A_P$?  If all the people in a school (staff and students included) like mathematics, is it true that the students all like mathematics?

Comment: I got how $A\subseteq A_P$ holds for all primes P.